# is it possible to upload several sketches to an Arduino board

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I have a project that is divided into two sections
each one of them requires an independent sketch,
I wanna upload the two sketches into the same Arduino card without one of them ruining the other's work, is that possible? if yes how to please
if no any other alternatives

Comment: And how the Arduino going to know which one to run? And no, there is no scenario in which you might need two sketches that cannot be refactored into one.

Comment: Arduino sketch programs only have a single thread of execution. It's just not possible to run different sketches simultaneously. Besides, how would hardware access work if there were two or more sketshes running, all competing for the same hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

But you could combine both rather independent parts and add some logic to find out which part should be active, currently.

E.g. When a button (-combination) is pressed at restart, Arduino runs the test mode, else it runs in standard mode.

You can have multiple tabs in the Arduino IDE to handle the modes more independently, but all code is coexisting in flash memory after upload.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have two seperate bin files (IDE menu Sketch / Export compiled binary) and have both of them include OTA code so you can update the binary as needed. The bin files can be stored locally on an SD card or remotely on a web server if the board has networking capabilities. Once updated the processor will reboot and start with updated code.

Look at [ArduinoOTA](https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA) for more information.